# Is there an issue with the required rep to vote to close a post?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges

I was looking around Game Development the other day and I seen this:

[image: Close link is visible on GameDev]

It is obvious that I have the privilege to vote to close post there. But when I looked at a post on Arqade:

[image: Close link is not visible on Gaming]

it is obvious that I don't have the privilege, even though I have more reputation on Arqade.

Is this a bug, or do the privileges work differently between these sites?

Comment: Is there any way you can make those images less...giant?

Comment: Is the first one by chance your own post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3000 rep is required to vote to close on this site.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering why that was.

Answer (score 8):

Using the information I could gather, I found the post in the first screenshot was [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153510/how-to-add-prefabs-to-the-terrain-and-still-retain-scripts-colliders-etc), which is your own. You can cast close votes on your own posts starting at 250 reputation (and you can delete your own posts that meet certain criteria, which is why delete is visible too).

Casting close votes on other questions requires 3,000 reputation.

Comment: Oooohhhh.... ok. I didn't know it matter.